# Weekly users reputation score hasn't reset for the new week

Tags: bug

It's Sunday, UTC time, so that means the [weekly rep tally](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=week) should've reset in the Users page.

But it hasn't:

[image]

Is this a bug? Or has Stack Overflow re-defined the start-of-week?

Comment: It is now Monday UTC and this still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Or all those users gained rep really fast :P

Comment: It is reset for me. In other date instances on the site, they will set things to run until it is no longer a given day *anywhere in the world*... perhaps that's what they have running here. That would mean it wouldn't change until 12PM UTC on Monday if it were supposed to reset first thing Monday morning.

Comment: @TylerH It resets Sunday, though, not Monday. Sunday is the first day of the SE "week".

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I don't know what to tell you since I am getting here 24 hours late but I can't repro this now either way.

Comment: @TylerH It's hitting a bunch of the network... it's still wrong on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week), actually... from what I can tell. Glorfindel hasn't earned 500+ rep in two days.

Comment: @TylerH I don't know, but it _still_ hasn't reset for me, even though it shows my rep count for the week (some 500+) accurately. I'm stuck on the 5th page for some reason. Bizarre.